# Comparing 4 groups of unequal sizes and non-normal distribution

Tags: anova, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I have 4 groups of students. Each student was asked to give us the number of reports they wrote through the semester.The 4 groups have `n` ranging from 5 to 250 members across groups. Each of the groups had different interventions, and I'm trying to compare if the number of reports written by one group differed from another.

Given that the samples are non-normally distributed and the sample sizes are varying to such a large degree, what are some of the tests I can use for the same?

Would be happy to provide more details if necessary.